# How to create a mIRC Dialog Side Menu?

Tags: mirc

I have quite a lot of knowledge of programming for mIRC, making scripts and whatnot but now I'm delving into creating a dialog so I can create a bot for people of which they can fine tune to their channels needs.

[image]

I would like to create a similar dialog to the above, of which I only need help on creating the menu, whereas I currently have one similar to the JQuery tab switcher.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to have a side menu where you're able to expand and collapse the categories, if this is possible to achieve?

Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you want enhanced mIRC dialog object, you should read about DCX, it's buggy and it's development has stopped for a long time, but it's still the best mIRC extension for mIRC dialog.
After the first learning curve you will love it.

Answer (score 0):

Very buggy indeed and a totally abandoned project -- even the websites hosting the forum and docs for it are long gone.

I had nearly completed an elaborate control panel which would give other users complete control (with full remote capability) over my mIRC game bots when I ran into several issues that were never resolved by the DCX devs.  This effectively rendered the bot operator front end scheme useless; much time and effort wasted.

If you keep your design simple/basic, you may have better luck.